# Did "sublime" and "cherubim" rhyme in the past?

Tags: pronunciation, lyrics, rhymes, christmas, songs

In my choir we are currently practicing some carols, including *[See amid the the winter's snow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/See,_amid_the_Winter's_Snow)*, which was written by Edward Caswall (1814–1878). Its six verses and refrain each have two pairs of very clear rhymes, except for the second verse:

> Lo, within a manger lies
>   He who built the starry skies;
>   He who, throned in height sublime,
>   Sits amid the cherubim

The words "sublime" and "cherubim" don't rhyme (IPA: [/səˈblaɪm/](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sublime) vs. [/ˈtʃɛrəbɪm/](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cherubim)). However, it seems possible that there was a different pronunciation due to regional accents, changes in the language over time, etc.

Was "sublime" pronounced "sub-LIM" or was "cherubim" pronounced "cheru-BAIM"?

I find it hard to believe that Caswall wrote two lines that aren't supposed to rhyme when the other 26 obviously are rhyming.

Comment: The rhyme is close enough for a poet.

Comment: Goss probably took a poetic licence here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's questioning poetic license.

Comment: Many times in poetry a writer will use a near rhyme (a near miss, if you will) and select a word spelled similarly but doesn't actually rhyme.

Comment: Is this really off-topic? The question is wether the words can or cannot be pronounced in a certain way, not wether the author has the right or not to take liberties. There are plenty of cases were words have variations in pronunciation explained by regional accents, changes in the language over time etc.

Comment: This question is about pronounciation, not about poetry. @Jonatan I suggest you listen to the performances found on YouTube.

Comment: The recordings I've found indicates that no one tries to make the lines rhyme. My OCD is hurting. ;-)

Comment: @Jonatan - could Goss have originally meant to use the French  term "sublime" which actually rhymes with cherubim.

Comment: Someone can pronounce poetry any way they want.  William Blake's *The Tyger* is a case in point -- some people pronounce the words more or less "normally" while others try to contort them to rhyme.  And both groups insist that their way is the way Blake would prefer.

Comment: Similar: *[Was the pronunciation of “symmetry” different in the past?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216345)*

Comment: No, the two words do not rhyme. But they have the same vowel (i) and consonant (m). This is one type of a *half rhyme* or *slant rhyme*. There is plenty of information about this on the internet. For example, on [Literary Devices](http://www.literarydevices.com/half-rhyme/)

Comment: I think it's a perfectly reasonable consonance rhyme and that it would go unnoticed if the song was based on assonance and consonance rhyming.

Comment: Reminds me of Lana Del Rey's song "Radio". The lyrics go: "Lick me up and take me like a vitamin / 'Cause my body's sweet like sugar venom, oh yeah" -- where "vitamin" was pronounced as "vit-uh-min". Lots of songwriters and poets do this. As Alan stated, it's called a half/slant rhyme.

Comment: To all the close-voters, this is not off-topic. The poem is motivation for wondering about pronunciation. Maybe there are some dialects in which these two rhyme, very reasonable question.

Comment: Watched a TV program about Shakespeare just recently, where they showed that many sonnets that don't rhyme very well _did_ rhyme when they were written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the French pronunciation of *sublime*: /syblim/, and the Hebrew pronunciation of the *-im* ending: /-im/, they both rhyme with *seem*.

I very much doubt that's the way Edward Caswell intended you to pronounce the hymn.

[Walker's pronouncing dictionary](https://archive.org/details/walkerspronounc00unkngoog) from 1828 says that *sublime* and *cherubim* were pronounced the same way then as they are today.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, this is just an *eye rhyme*:

> Agreement in spelling, but not in sound, of the ends of words or of lines of verse, as in *have*, *grave*.

([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sight-rhyme))

Answer (score -7):

Sublime and cherubim have different vowel length. One is /ai/ the other is /il