# Why did Blake spell "tyger" with a "y"?

Tags: orthography, poetry

In the poem [THE TYGER](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems-and-poets/poems/detail/43687) by William Blake:

> **Tyger Tyger**, burning bright,
>   In the forests of the night;
>   What immortal hand or eye,
>   Could frame thy fearful symmetry?

Why is "Tiger" spelled *Tyger*, with a `y`?

If it's just a difference in the orthography (or lack of convention) at the time, why don't modern editors update the spelling?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

SUPPLEMENTAL:

There are two reasons for not "updating the spelling".

The first is that scholars are reluctant to tamper with an author's work; they do so only in order to make works which would otherwise be unintelligible accessible to a larger audience. There's no evident need to update "The Tyger" to make this poem accessible.

The second is that Blake was not only a poet but an accomplished visual artist—he made his living as an engraver—and he published many of his works, including "The Tyger" as visual compositions. These cannot be modernized if you want to encounter them as Blake presented them to his own public.

[image]

*(This image of the page was published by the [Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/artanddesign/jonathanjonesblog/2014/nov/18/william-blake-the-tyger-art-poem-tigers), credited to 'Photograph:British Museum'.)*

Comment: Flammable felines. What a weird subject for poetry.

Comment: Doesn't answer why he spelled it that way.

Comment: @fredsbend As I said, the answer is 'supplemental' to J. Siebeneichler's answer to the primary question -- that's why I made it a CW.

Comment: Can you provide the source reference for that image?  I'd prefer the ISBN of the hardcopy book, or a link to anyone selling the hardcopy now.  Thanks.

Comment: That is one startled-looking tiger. I mean tyger.

Comment: @Stony Didn't notice that ... I plead the fifth.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft That's a photograph of the page from Songs of Experience as Blake himself published it; I've added a link to the source. Very fine reproductions of all Blake's works are available from the [William Blake Archive](www.blakearchive.org/) at the University of Virginia.

Answer (score 42):

*Tyger* is an archaic spelling that was used alongside *tiger*; it is safe to assume it was a standard spelling since it occurs in old encyclopedias and dictionaries.

According to the Google Ngram data (see picture), both spellings had a similar ratio of use until the early 1800s, when *tiger* became the prevalent form (perhaps because they realised that there is no etymological justification for using a Y). Nowadays *tyger* is quite rare in spontaneous use, but it is still visible due to the popularity of William Blake's poem.[image: Usage of the words *tyger* (blue) vs. *tiger* in the English corpus between 1600 and 2000]

Comment: Not to mention the way he rhymes "eye" and "symmetry".

Comment: @Andrew so it's supposed to be read "symmetr/ai/" ?

Comment: Old poems rhyme a lot better in a Birmingham accent.

Comment: As an important point of reference, Blake published "The Tyger" in 1794.

Comment: @PierreArlaud  I don't really know, I just assume that, as Blake spoke (spake?) them they probably rhymed.  [Relevant Shakespeare.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPlpphT7n9s)

Comment: @Andrew That's what I assumed considering he makes "skies" rhyme with "eyes" further in the poem… But you know maybe the plural's different as well.

Comment: @PierreArlaud: In short, yes. Or else it's supposed to be read "symmetr/ee/" but sort of winked at and pretended like it rhymes. ;)  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216345/was-the-pronunciation-of-symmetry-different-in-the-past

Comment: Interesting that the use of "tyger" almost slavishly follows that of "tiger", following a delay of 10-15 years (till about 1750). Is there a cause-effect relationship?!

Comment: FWIW, my hometown's city school system are proud T-Y tygers. http://www.tygerpride.com