# Was the "i" long or short in Shakespeare's plays?

Tags: pronunciation, shakespeare

In Queen Gertrude's short opening monologue the final two lines seem to have rhymed in Shakespeare's day:

> Good Hamlet, cast thy nighted colour off,
>   And let thine eye look like a friend on Denmark.
>   Do not for ever with thy vailed lids
>   Seek for thy noble father in the dust:
>   Thou know'st 'tis common; all that lives must die,
>   Passing through nature to eternity.

Query: was the "i" long or short? Was it "dee" and "e-ter-nit-ee" or "dye" and "e-ter-nit-eye"?

Comment: Assuming we were still somewhat reeling under the Norman cosh back then, it might be worth considering Modern French pronunciation of ***éternité***.

Comment: But those lines may never have rhymed, simply being an "eye-rhyme" or "printer's rhyme". I can't imagine the *-y* of *eternity* being anything but short (since it derives from the French *éternité,* as @FumbleFingers has pointed out.

Comment: *Die* started out being pronounced *dee* before [the Great Vowel Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift). When Shakespeare wrote, the shift had already started, so *die* had already shifted away from *dee*. But I don't know the details.

Comment: There are still English accents where 'eternity' comes close to being pronounced 'e-ter-nit-eye'. I would never claim to be any kind of expert in Brummy (Birmingham) or Black Country speech, but from a dozen years in Smethwick and Oldbury, I'd say that 'eternity' can be close to 'e-ter-nit-eye', though maybe more like half way between 'eternitay' and 'eternitoy'. Only at the end of a phrase though, you wouldn't get that sound in eg 'eternity-ring'.  With huge apologies to any Brummies and Black Country folks for mangling your bostin words.

Comment: @Spagirl: Very interesting. It's possible then that both *die* and *eternity* could have been partway between pre-Great Vowel Shift *dee* and present-day *die* when Shakespeare wrote.

Comment: @PeterShor: C'est possible. However, I must point out that two centuries later Lord Byron wrote: "Of his departure had been sent him by ...  His Spanish friends for those in Italy." Two CENTURIES later. Is it Italee or Ital-eye? Or something in between?

Comment: @Ricky: Two centuries later, I believe that pronunciation was more or less the same as it is today. But the Romantic poets kept rhyming *eye* and *symmetry* because Shakespeare and the other Elizabethans had given them leave to.

Comment: @PeterShor: How very conservative of them!

Comment: @Ricky: Alexander Pope, in *the Rape of the Lock*, written 75 years before the Romantic poets, rhymes *casuistry* with *flea*. I don't know how the tradition of retro rhymes got started among the Romantics.

Comment: It's almost the exact same rhyme as found in *The Tyger*, where in 1794 Blake rhymes *eye* with *symmetry*

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216345/was-the-pronunciation-of-symmetry-different-in-the-past

Answer (score 4):

TLDR: The words *die, see, eternity* probably ended in three distinct vowels and diphthongs when Shakespeare wrote, but they were all quite close in sound, and in the neighborhood of the vowels *bead* and *bid* today. So *die* and *eternity* was a good near-rhyme.

There is quite a bit of information on this in the comments on [this Language Log post.](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=1421) I will summarize. One of the commenters says:

> Miege (1688), for example, distinguishes three pronunciations of the letter /y/: as analogous to French /i/ in angry, ready, etc; as like "the broad English i" in my, cry, etc. and as an "e masculine" in "substantives derived from the Latin," such as charity, amity, and liberality. This last, presumably, was a barred i or other centralized vowel.

An "e masculine" is the French term for the vowel /e/, as in *café*. I don't believe this French vowel has changed that much since 1688, so the vowel of *eternity* was probably something in the vicinity of /e/ or /ɪ/. In the 20th century, *eternity* still had the vowel /ɪ/ in some dialects.

Meanwhile, the vowel of *die* was undergoing the [Great Vowel Shift.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift) It started as /iː/ in 15th century (and earlier) Middle English, and went through /ɪi/, /əi/, /ʌi/, and ended up at today's value /ai/ by the early 20th century. If you look at the chart in [Wikipedia,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift) it was somewhere around /ɪi/ or /əi/ in Shakespeare's time.

The vowel /ɪ/ and the diphthong /ɪi/ rhyme really well. If these were the pronunciations Shakespeare used, then *die* would have been a better rhyme for *eternity* than *tree* would have. (By the Great Vowel Shift chart, *tree* had reached its current value of /iː/ when Shakespeare wrote, although *east* had not).

If you look at Shakespeare's sonnets, he rhymes *die* with *memory*, but he also rhymes *free* with *legacy*. One assumes that both of these could not have been perfect rhymes, since the vowels of *die* and *free* never merged. However, the rhyme of *die* and *memory* was presumably a much better rhyme for Shakespeare than it is today.